# Grade calculator program

Tags: java, loops

I'm totally stuck on this project, in which a user is supposed to enter number of students in a class, and number of exams taken. Then they enter each student's name, and then the exam scores for that student on a single line separated by blank spaces. The program calculates each student's average and the corresponding letter grade.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class proj2 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Welcome to Gradecalculator!");

  System.out.println("Please enter the number of students:");
  int students = s.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Please enter the number of exams:");
  int exams = s.nextInt();

  int i = 0;
  int studentnumber = 1;

  int sum = 0;  
  while (i < students) {

    double average = sum/exams;

    System.out.println("Enter student " + studentnumber++ + "'s name :");
    String studentname = s.next();

    System.out.println("Enter exam scores :");

    for (; i < exams; i++) {    
     int n = s.nextInt();
     sum+=n;

     if (n < 0) {
     System.out.println("Invalid exam scores, reenter: ");      
     }
  }
  if (average <= 100 && average >= 90) {
       System.out.println("Letter grade: A");
       System.out.println(studentname + " gets 4 stars! ****");
      } if (average <= 89 && average >= 80) {
       System.out.println("Letter grade: B");
       System.out.println(studentname + " gets 3 stars! ***");
      } if (average <= 79 && average >= 70) {
       System.out.println("Letter grade: C");
       System.out.println(studentname + " gets 2 stars! **");
      } if (average <= 69 && average >= 60) {
       System.out.println("Letter grade: D");
       System.out.println(studentname + " gets 1 star! *");
      } if (average <= 59) {
       System.out.println("Letter grade: F");
       System.out.println(studentname + " gets 0 stars!");
      }
}
 }
 }
```

This is the output I get as of now:

```
Welcome to Gradecalculator!
```

Please enter the number of students:
3
Please enter the number of exams:
3
Enter student 1's name :
sam
Enter exam scores :
80 80 80
Letter grade: F
sam gets 0 stars!

Obviously three 80's should be a B first of all, so I'm obviously not calculating the average properly, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditions should look like this :

```
if (average <= 100 && average >=90)
```

not like this :

```
if (average <= 100 & average >=90)
```

You want to use logical AND and not bitwise AND.

Another problem is that you reset `sum` to 0 in each iteration, so you are not actually accumulating the sum.

Finally, the calculation of the average and all the conditions should be outside the for loop, since you want to read all the inputs before calculating the average.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change but still when I enter three 100's for the exam scores I get the message saying the letter grade is an F. I don't understand why it's not calculating the average properly.

Comment: Aha. That makes sense. Ok, I declared the variable outside of the loop now and my new output when I enter three 80 scores is this: Letter grade: F
john gets 0 stars!
Letter grade: F
john gets 0 stars!
Letter grade: B
john gets 3 stars! *** - So clearly my loop is screwed up. But at least now it's calculating the sum correctly.

Comment: @sam If you move your `if` conditions outside the for loop, as I suggested, you should only get a single output of `Letter grade: ..."

Comment: Oh yeah, this is another thing I should have mentioned. When I move the if conditions outside of the loop, it tells me that "average" cannot be resolved to variable. Am I declaring the average variable in the wrong location?

Comment: @sam If you are going to use `average` outside the loop, you should declare it outside the loop.

Comment: I've updated the original post to reflect my code after changes you suggested. The output only does one letter grade now which is good, but it's still giving me an average of 0 and letter grade F. I moved the sum variable declaration outside of the loop but it's still not working.

Comment: @sam You still have `double average = sum/exams;` inside the loop. It should be after the loop.

Comment: Ah! That did it. Thank you so much. I'm sure I'll run into more trouble but at least you got me this far.

Comment: Ok so I'm getting close I think. But now when I enter all of the exam scores and get the correct letter grade back, the program stops. I need it to go back to beginning of the loop and ask me to enter the next student's name and grades until I've reached the number of students entered. Not sure why it isn't doing that since the while loop is set to the "i<students" condition.

Comment: @Sam you're using the same index i for both loops. Don't.

Comment: Thanks again. You've been so helpful. I'll stop torturing you now.

Answer (score 0):

You have done a small mistake here.

```
if (average <= 100 & average >= 90)
```

I think you're trying to use logical `AND` use double `&`like this.

```
if (average <= 100 && average >= 90)
```

and you need to change your code little more. You need to declare `sum` outside `for` loop because every time its getting reset to `0`.

```
int sum = 0;
for (; i < exams; i++) {  
   int n = s.nextInt();
   sum+=n;
}
double average = sum/exams;
```

Comment: Thanks, I moved the declaration of the sum variable outside the loop but it still seems to be coming out as 0 no matter what I enter.